# What is a good design for accumulating temporary data stemming from several processing runs?

Tags: design-patterns, c++, data-structures

I would like to compute cycle times for some manipulator movements. These movements consist of different phases. I have a class that models these phases and this is its constructor to give an idea:

```
/**
 * \brief Creates a new instance.
 *
 * \param name phase name
 * \param startIndex phase start point index with respect to the manipulator
 * path's path point container
 * \param stopIndex phase stop point index with respect to the manipulator
 * path's path point container
 * \param speed speed in mm/s for this phase
 * \param startPauseTime waiting time in seconds at the start point
 * \param haltAtStop whether to halt (speed 0 mm/s) at the stop point
 */
Phase(const std::string& name, int startIndex, int stopIndex, double speed,
        double startPauseTime, bool haltAtStop) :
        name(name),
        startIndex(startIndex), stopIndex(stopIndex), speed(speed),
        startPauseTime(startPauseTime), haltAtStop(haltAtStop)
{
}
```

Phases are defined by the input of the cycle time estimation. They could be `const`, for they do not need to change.

Now while the cycle time estimator processes the phases, it computes additional information like maximum reachable speeds, maximum allowed speeds and so on. It is a peculiarity that the phases influence each other. The maximum allowed end speed for one phase is determined for example by whether the succeeding phase requires the manipulator to decelerate vehemently. So these values can only be computed by processing all the phases, but they belong to exactly one phase.

After this preprocessing, cycle times can be computed. They also belong to exactly one phase.

Now I wonder where to store this accumulating data.

1. Should it be stored within `Phase`? Then `Phase` would need to be non-`const`. This is somehow elegant, because the data is collected at a single position. On the other hand it "feels" wrong, because input data, intermediate data and result data is mixed and input data cannot be declared `const` even though it of course may never change. Also a succeeding display method that would display a phase and its cycle time also "accidentally" gets the intermediate data which is of absolutely no use after the cycle time estimation has finished.
2. My solution has been to create another class `PhaseData` for the intermediate data and store it within indexed containers such that the phase index conforms with the phase data index.

`PhaseData` looks like this:

```
/**
 * \brief This class collects computed data for a cycle phase.
 */
class PhaseData
{
public:

    /** Length of the Phase Trajectory in mm */
    double trajectoryLength;

    /** Actual Final Speed in mm/s */
    double endSpeed;

    /** Maximum Final Speed in mm/s That Still Allows Required Deceleration */
    double maximumEndSpeed;
};
```

And the result (cycle time) I have connected to the input data by creating a container storing `pair`s of input and output:

```
using Result = std::vector<std::pair<Phase, double>>;
```

This works, but it also "feels" wrong, because the structure becomes quite complex and for building the result container, the phases are copied. Also relying on conforming indices might be error-prone.

Is there a standard way to deal with such accumulation of data where some data is (const) input data, some data is temporary and some data is result data? Or has anyone found a clever solution for that? Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't be afraid of copying data (or, having multiple or redundant copies of data), especially if doing so allows you to code more elegantly (lowering the source code complexity and maintenance cost), unless your code runs on severely memory-constrained environment (and you absolutely need to push the limits of the application's capability).

Comment: For the new data type that exists strictly in between two adjacent pieces of input data, it is similar to an interposer. If you can have a sequential data structure (e.g. a vector) that can store **either** a piece of input data **or** a piece of interposer, you will be able to picture that idea.

Comment: Vector will be the easiest to work with (in fact, with cleaner code, since it corresponds to how most programmers think, imperatively), whereas any sequential data structure capable of bidirectional iterator is also technically suitable.

Comment: @rwong My main concern with storing temporary computation results in classes is not memory consumption, but that it distracts or confuses the software developer. In the "second life" of the `Phase` classes, they are used to display the cycle time estimation results. It would be much more elegant, if irrelevant data could be discarded. Therefore I prefer the second way right now...

Comment: I tend to favor the functional style in these cases, like `const A a=phase1(...); const B b=phase2(a); const C c=phase3(b);` The temporary data would be stored locally in these functions, the input data would be passed in as `const` and not mutated, and the output data is cleanly separated from the rest and used as inputs for the next phase(s). Copying overhead can usually be optimized to a degree if they show up as hotspots and this type of approach eliminates temporal coupling. It also allows you to safely multithread it as a parallel pipeline if that's applicable and eases testing.